# Strange ambiguity in HttpMethodAttribute in dot Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-core

I have notices unexpected bahaviour of MVC routes in .Net Core. As I did not expected that behaviuor and I dont know simple way to fix it, I ask for your help. :)

```
[HttpPut("obj/{pk?}")]
public IActionResult SaveObj(decimal? pk, [FromBody] ObjDef obj)
{
[..]
}
```

Everything is working correctly. I can add new object by requesting Put on `/obj` and update it by requesting `/obj/1`.

My suprise is that when I request put on uri like `/obj/AStringValue` the SaveObj method still gets invoked, with empty PK value, so new obj is created if request have correct payload.

My expectation was to get 404 header as clearly there is no such path declared in any of my controllers.

As a workaround I have made two methods - one with mandatory decimal parametr PK and other with no parameters at all, but then the one with decimal PK still got fired, with pk equal to 0! This is utterly incorrect in my opinion.

How should I deal with this behaviour? Or am I doing something wrong here...

My version of AspNetCore MVC is 2.2.0

Comment: Why is your pk a nullable decimal? In fact why is it a decimal? I would generally use an integer or a guid for my primary key. I assume you are attempting to use a single method for the insert and update. If this is the case I would suggest rather don't pass the pk and just check the obj to see if it has an id or not before deciding on insert or update to the database.

Comment: Well, it just is a decmial - it is not related to my question, so I will not describe it any futher. 
And as for reading pk from object - it would work as a workaround, but such API is not aglined with my conception of proper REST, where each object have own path and requesting GET, PUT and DELETE on that path You can operate on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [route constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-constraint-reference) to validate the type of a route parameter. If the constraint fails, a 404 is returned, as though the route didn't exist at all. In your case, you can use the `decimal` constraint, like this:

```
[HttpPut("obj/{pk:decimal?}")]
```

This states that `pk` is optional, but when it is provided, it must be a valid decimal value.